# One liner in Ruby for displaying a prompt, getting input, and assigning to a variable?

Tags: ruby, input

Often I find myself doing the following:

```
print "Input text: "
input = gets.strip
```

Is there a graceful way to do this in one line? Something like:

```
puts "Input text: #{input = gets.strip}"
```

The problem with this is that it waits for the input before displaying the prompt. Any ideas?

Comment: Make it a function that takes the prompt text and returns the input text?  If you want to get fancier and need multiple prompt/input cycles you could make the function take an array of prompts and a Block then loop over the prompts and yield each input.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Check out [highline](http://github.com/JEG2/highline):

```
require "highline/import"
input = ask "Input text: "
```

Answer (score 79):

I think going with something like what Marc-Andre suggested is going to be the way to go, but why bring in a whole ton of code when you can just define a two line function at the top of whatever script you're going to use:

```
def prompt(*args)
    print(*args)
    gets
end

name = prompt "Input name: "
```

Comment: Indeed, that will work fine too. Until you want to add some input checking. Or some default value. Or not show what's typed because you ask for a password...

Comment: For a 5-second script, I would say that this is the way to go.

Comment: I would attach the `.chomp` method after `gets` otherwise the variable would contain a `\n` newline character at the end.

Answer (score 34):

One liner hack sure. Graceful...well not exactly.

```
input = [(print 'Name: '), gets.rstrip][1]
```

Comment: I think `input = (print 'Name: '; gets.rstrip)` is more readable. But both solutions have problems with `nil` values. In Ruby 2.3 they can be handled gracefully with `input = (print 'Name: '; gets&.rstrip)`.

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is old, but I though I'd show what I use as my standard method for getting input.

```
require 'readline'

def input(prompt="", newline=false)
  prompt += "\n" if newline
  Readline.readline(prompt, true).squeeze(" ").strip
end
```

This is really nice because if the user adds weird spaces at the end or in the beginning, it'll remove those, and it keeps a history of what they entered in the past (Change the `true` to `false` to not have it do that.). And, if `ARGV` is not empty, then `gets` will try to read from a file in `ARGV`, instead of getting input. Plus, `Readline` is part of the Ruby standard library so you don't have to install any gems. Also, you can't move your cursor when using `gets`, but you can with `Readline`.

And, I know the method isn't one line, but it is when you call it

```
name = input "What is your name? "
```

Comment: "NOTE: [[`Readline::readline`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html#method-c-readline)] terminates ruby interpreter and does not return the terminal status after user pressed ‘^C’ when wait inputting line."

Comment: I like this and @Andrew Grimm's suggestion as the best alternatives to using `highline/import`

Comment: Check out https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-prompt

Answer (score 12):

Following @Bryn's lead:

```
def prompt(default, *args)
  print(*args)
  result = gets.strip
  return result.empty? ? default : result
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your proposed solution is that the string to be printed can't be built until the input is read, stripped, and assigned.  You could separate each line with a semicolon:

```
$ ruby -e 'print "Input text: "; input=gets.strip; puts input'
Input text: foo
foo
```

Comment: That is not really one-line; you are using semicolons and that would probably not fit the graceful part of his request.

Comment: $ ruby -e 'print("Input text: ")||(input=gets.strip)&&(puts input)'

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Inquirer](https://github.com/arlimus/inquirer.rb) gem by chance and I really like it, I find it way more neat and easy to use than Highline, though it lacks of input validation by its own.
Your example can be written like this

```
require 'inquirer'
inputs = Ask.input 'Input text'
```