# Ruby - If "yes" abc... end if "no" xyz

Tags: ruby, if-statement, boolean

I am working on a ruby syntax. This is what I have:

```
puts "Do you like books?"
if "yes" 
  puts "I do too"
end
if  "no"
  puts "Movies better"
end
```

When I save and run this code, nothing happens.
I expect it to display either statement based on 
a yes or no answer. 
How d I rewrite it to work?

Comment: Paste the code you used.

Comment: Nothing happened because `query` is neither `"yes"` nor `"no"`, it's `"Do you like books?"`

Comment: I used this, and it did not work; puts "Do you like books?"
if  "yes" 
  puts "I do too"
end
if  "no"
  puts "Movies better"
end

Comment: You set the value of `query` to `"Do you like books?"`. Then you are checking if `query` has the value `"yes"` which it does not (the value `"yes"` is not the same as the value `"Do you like books?") so the first `if` fails. Then you check if `query` has the value `"no"` which it also does not (the value `"no"` is not the same as the value `"Do you like books?"). So the second `if` fails. Therefore, your program outputs nothing.

Comment: You don't do anything to actually capture an answer, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/2889720/438992.

Comment: That link is confusing for me, at this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better way of expressing it:

```
puts "Do you like books?"

case (gets.chomp)
when 'yes'
  puts "I do too"
when 'no'
  puts "Movies better"
else
  puts "I don't know what you mean."
end
```

The `case` statement is great for breaking out multiple paths at the same time. `gets` grabs input from the user. `chomp` trims off the newline character that's automatically included.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much Tadman. I tried it and it works. Now I'll check each line to grasp exactly how to write this correctly. I appreciate it

Comment: Good to hear! When learning Ruby make sure you have a really good reference on hand. I started with the [pickaxe book](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby) but the [core documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/) is also pretty good once you get to know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the input from the user by using `gets` and stored it in a variable.
It looks something like this:

```
puts "Do you like this?"
answer = gets.strip

if answer.downcase == "yes"
  puts "Me too"
else
  puts "Whyyyy?"
end
```

### Note:

`strip` basically removes new line character.

`downcase` is to make the string all in lowercase. So regardless "Yes" or "YES", it will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Is your intent here to ask the user for input, and respond accordingly?

If so, other answers here provide examples of a way to do it (using `gets.chomp`) using only built-in Ruby facilities.  However, if you don't mind installing an extra library (or `gem`, in Ruby lingo), you could do:

```
gem install highline
```

And then re-write your code as follows:

```rb
require 'highline'

if HighLine.agree("Do you like books? ") # note added space; more below.
  puts "I do too" # if they answer yes or y, in any capitalization
else
  puts "Movies better" # if they answer no or n, in any capitalization
end
```

This prompts the user with the question `Do you like books?`, followed by a space, and leaving the cursor on the same line for input (if that part is not desired, drop the space and a newline will also be printed).  It then waits for input, and validates it, as follows:

1. If the user types "**yes**" or "**y**" (or "**Yes**", "**YES**", or even "**yEs**" — but not "**yees**"), `HighLine.agree` will return `true`, and your `puts` of "**I do too**" will be run.
2. If the user types "**no**" or "**n**" (any capitalization), `HighLine.agree` will return `false`, and your `puts` of "**Movies better**" will be run.
3. Given any other input, `HighLine.agree` will not yet return, instead prompting the user to "**Please enter "yes" or "no".**", and then repeating the question again.

Using a library like this has the benefit of someone else having already spent time thinking about edge cases, common shorthands (like "y" for "yes"), etc., and having the code handle all that with a single method to call.

Additionally, if you change the `require` line to:

```
require 'highline/import'
```

... then `agree` (and several other HighLine features) will be imported for you, so you can simply type `agree` instead of `HighLine.agree` when using it.

Further [documentation on HighLine](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/highline/HighLine) is available (it has a bunch of other features, including generating text-based menus, colorizing text, and more), as is [source code](https://github.com/JEG2/highline).