# Is it possible to break out of a ruby program if I input CTRL+D?

Tags: ruby

So following this [SO guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889720/one-liner-in-ruby-for-displaying-a-prompt-getting-input-and-assigning-to-a-var), I wrote a program such as:

**ruby_cli.rb**

```
while true
  input = [(print 'Name: '), gets.rstrip][1]
  input.downcase.strip
end
```

What I want to happen is when I press *CTRL+D* (which as I understand is EOF) at the command prompt, the ruby program breaks out of the while loop and ends.  Right now it hits the *input.downcase.strip* line and I get an error such as *undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)*

How would you accomplish this?

Edit:

The reason I am using *input = [(print 'Name: '), gets.rstrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889720/one-liner-in-ruby-for-displaying-a-prompt-getting-input-and-assigning-to-a-var)* is because I want to print "Name" as the prompt before every user input I ask for.

Comment: It might because you are not checking if gets results in EOF or not when the downcast line executes.

Comment: Please don't use `[(print 'Name: '), gets.rstrip][1]`. It's uglier and slower than simply writing it on two separate lines.

Comment: @Vikyboss, I was under an impression there is no such thing as "EOF" character?

Comment: You could call it a status/condition of a stream. In your case the stream is stdin.

Comment: Ruby version [2.1.0 documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) says `gets` would return nil on `EOF`. But in your case, somehow `rstrip` succeded on a `nil` and only the next line failed. I would suggest looking up the documentation of your ruby version.

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
loop do                   # infinite loop
  print 'Name: '          # prompt for input
  response = gets         # get the response -- gets returns nil on EOF
  break unless response   # break out of the loop unless the response is non-nil
  p response.rstrip.downcase   # do whatever you want with the response
end
```

EOF is `ctrl-d` for Unix/Mac, `ctrl-Z` for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking `gets` using a while loop, like this:

```
print 'Name: '
while line = gets
    # operate on line 
    print 'Name: '
end
```