# How to terminate Ruby array sort program using Nil entry

Tags: ruby

Noob rubyist here, working through "Learn to Program." I've set up the below code to take user entries and sort, but I can't figure out how to end the program on a nil entry instead of the 'done' that is currently set. Setting the user == '', obviously terminates before it takes any input. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
array = []
user = ''

puts "Type as many words as you like. Press enter to end."

until user == 'done'
    user = gets.chomp
    array.push user
end

puts
puts array.sort
```

Comment: Try `until user.nil?` (But how will you enter nil?)

Comment: @RayToal [ctrl-d or ctrl-z?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36525399/1672429)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your variable from `nil`, so that it executes the body at least the first time

```
user = nil

until user == ''
  user = gets.chomp
  array.push user
end
```

Comment: Perfect. I figured it was staring me in the face, but I just couldn't see it. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation that will not add the blank user to the array. Although it would be nice to use a construct more specific than `loop`, `loop` gives us exactly what we need.

```
users = []

loop do
  user = gets.chomp
  if user != ''
    users << user
  else
    break
  end
end

puts users
```

Answer (score 0):

Your message says "Press enter to end". So I suggest you get the user input in one go, split the string into words, sort and display.

```
user = ''

puts "Type as many words as you like. Press enter to end."   
user = gets.chomp
array = user.split 

puts array.sort
```