# Start Command Prompt with Ruby doesn't work

Tags: ruby

I can't get this to work with the Start Command Prompt with Ruby on windows.
I got this simple programm:

```
puts "Whats your name?"
name = gets
puts "Hello" + name + ". How are you?"
```

But if I call it with "ruby program.rb", instead for waiting for my input, it just prints out:

```
Whats your name?
Helloputs "Whats your name?"
. How are you?
```

It is like the "gets" command is not been recognized. Why does this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One liner in Ruby for displaying a prompt, getting input, and assigning to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889720/one-liner-in-ruby-for-displaying-a-prompt-getting-input-and-assigning-to-a-var)

Comment: That is not my question. It is like the gets command does not work.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are (somehow) passing the name of your programm two times on the command line. Your described behavior is reproducible when you are running

```
ruby program.rb program.rb
```

This works the way it does since `gets` does not read from `STDIN` in all cases. Instead, it prefers to read the files mentioned on the command line first. Only if there is no additional file on the command line, `gets` falls back to read from `STDIN`

The question on why you are passing the filename of your ruby program twi times is unfortunately less clear. If you are not calling it that way on your own, this might be caused by some strange environment options in your shell or due to your Ruby setup.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious as well, and found this link [How does gets and gets.chomp in ruby work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193813/how-does-gets-and-gets-chomp-in-ruby-work) 
Apparently it created a new line therefore could not find the name.

This seemed to work, (following the instructions in the link)

```
puts "Whats your name?"
name = gets
puts "Hello " + name.chomp + ". How are you?"
```

Have fun.

Also if you start using rails, you can also test in your console 
 Example

```
> def test1 
>     ...code .. 
> end  

> test1
```

Comment: Still, the command prompt should wait for my input. I want to type my name in, but it does not wait and just prints out the text. I really don't get why.

Comment: In your console (irb)... try doing this... def test  puts "Whats your name?"
name = gets
puts "Hello " + name.chomp + ". How are you?" end   Then run test. It works for me.

Comment: I also make a test.rb with the code... puts "Whats your name?"
name = gets
puts "Hello " + name.chomp + ". How are you?" ... it worked > ruby test.rb

Answer (score 1):

@Ray Ban I have used your code

```
puts "Whats your name?"
name = gets
puts "Hello" + name + ". How are you?"
```

in gets.rb file and run it using $ ruby gets.rb and it worked as expected.

I am using ruby-2.3.0